# (nginx) Redirect 301 from location to another domain

Tags: redirect, nginx

Need to redirect location (mydomain.com/x) to another domain (newdomain.com)

Tried:

```
location /x { rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com redirect; }
```

Not working... 
can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to capture the url portion after `/x` and rewrite it at the end of the new location:

```
location /x {
       rewrite ^/x(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com$1 redirect;
}
```